# Форма [Сабмит Формы Запоминание данных]

Tags: html, javascript, php

```
<form id="form" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="text" name="uname">
     <input type="password" name="upass">
     <input type="submit" id="submit" name="usubmit">
</form>
```

Разве после сабмита браузер не должен предлагать запоминать данные? Хром чего-то не предлагает, подскажите, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, укажите значение параметра **action**. Хром не предложит вам сохранить пароль на той же странице.

Во-вторых, про настройки в браузере, думаю, спрашивать не надо? Возможно, там ваш домен указан как "не запоминать для данного сайта".

Внимательно посмотрите, появляется ли иконка "ключа" в конце адресной строки. Нажмите на неё, и там указать либо **Запоминать**, либо **Отмена**.

Comment: Менял action, все равно не хочет.

Настройки проверял, все норм, ключика нет.

Почему в лисе работает а в хроме - нет?

Comment: Хм. Я просто скопировал твой код, запустил у себя. Хром сразу предложил сохранить пароль. Скорее всего, дело в самом браузере, что-то с настройками.
И я с сервера запускал. Простая html страница не предложит сохранить.